# 2 subordinate clauses

Tags: conditionals

I said, “I will swim today only if I go to the beach if it is sunny today.”

Does the “if it is sunny today” clause modify “I will swim today only if I go to the beach” or does it only modify “I go to the beach”? My guess is the former answer because an if clause has to modify an independent clause or main clause.

Please let me know if my reasoning is correct or if my sentence is so ambiguous that both interpretations are valid.

Comment: The sentence is confusing because it doesn't clearly establish which clauses relate to one another. When people have to discuss something like this, they'll make it as clear as possible by saying something like "If it's sunny, I will go to the beach and swim."

Comment: Your sentence is unintelligible. These would be more idiomatic. "If it's sunny today and I go to the beach, I might swim" or "If it's sunny today I may go to the beach and swim" or "If it's sunny today and (if) I (decide to) go to the beach, maybe I'll (have a) swim."

Comment: Or, using "only", you *could* say, "I'll go to the beach for a swim today, but only if it's sunny." Or "If it's sunny today I'll have a swim, but only if I go to the beach." [That's a pretty stupid thing to say though.]